# Sample size calculation for multilevel, longitudinal experiment

Tags: sample-size, experiment-design, multilevel-analysis

I'd be grateful for any advice about how to do a sample size calculation for the following design.  We are interested in the impact of two variations of an intervention on hospital in-patients' perceptions of the quality of the nursing care they received.  Therefore, there will be three conditions, including control.

Research will be carried out in a number of hospitals; the hospitals themselves will probably not be sampled from a population: they will be hospitals that are willing to participate in the study. There will likely be a small number (say three). Within each hospital, a number of units (called wards in the UK) will again not be sampled, but they will be randomly assigned to one of the three conditions, so that there are equal numbers of units in each hospital in each arm.

The interventions are at the unit level, in that they are aimed at the nurses that work in the unit.  However, the outcome variable is derived from a survey of a sample of patients that were treated in the unit. New samples of patients will be surveyed at 3 monthly intervals for up to 18 months. In a pilot study, the outcome variable was the mean patient satisfaction score for each unit at each time.

The statistic of interest is the interaction between experimental condition and number of months since the start of the experiment.

My questions are:

1. How to calculate the required number of patients to sample in each unit at each time?
2. How to calculate the required number of units per condition in each hospital?
3. Is it appropriate to use mean scores at the unit level as the outcome measure, or would it be better to use individual patient responses as the outcome?

Thanks for any help!

David